# How to extract top 10 billionaire individuals from every Country

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have a table named `Billionaires` having attributes `Country`, `Name`, `Net Worth`, of billionaire individuals from every country.

I want the top 10 individuals from every country having the highest net worth with their net worth summed up.

The sample output is like

| Country | TotalNetworth |
| --- | --- |
| US. | 500000000000 |
| India. | 300000000000 |

And so on.

My code that I tried:

```sql
Select Country, Sum(NetWorth) over (partition by country) as TotalNetworth
From Billionaires
```

Comment: How to I pick only the top 10 individuals from every country and have my result grouped by country.

Comment: *I want the top 10 individuals* - so where is that in your query?

Comment: See the linked duplicate, only use `WHERE rn <= 10` instead.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possible approaches.  Here is an example.

```
SELECT Country, SUM(NetWorth) AS TotalNetWorth
FROM (
    SELECT Country, NetWorth, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Country ORDER BY NetWorth) AS NetWorthRank
    FROM Billionaires
    ) AS sub
WHERE NetWorthRank < 11
GROUP BY Country
```

Answer (score 1):

DENSE_RANK() function is suitable here for retrieving country wise top 10 individual Billionaires. If two person have same net worth in a country then consider it 1 not 2. DENSE_RANK() provides the rank without no gaps.

```
-- SQL SERVER
SELECT t.Country
     , SUM(t.NetWorth) TotalNetworth
FROM (SELECT Country
           , NetWorth
           , DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Country ORDER BY NetWorth DESC) rank_num
      FROM Billionaires) t
WHERE t.rank_num <= 10
GROUP BY t.Country;
```

But if need country wise top 10 Billionaires name who have highest worth then use below query where if two persons of a country have same networth then count is 2 not 1.

```
-- SQL SERVER
SELECT t.Country
     , SUM(t.NetWorth) TotalNetworth
FROM (SELECT Country
           , NetWorth
           , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Country ORDER BY NetWorth DESC) rank_num
      FROM Billionaires) t
WHERE t.rank_num <= 10
GROUP BY t.Country;
```